# check against primary key in postgresql?

Tags: php, postgresql

I have a 10 database tables each have primary keys with different names

now i want to write a single function in PHP to retrieve all data based on the primary key

i.e

```
function getdatabyid("table_name",primary_key_value)
```

I want to build a query in such way that when i send these two variables to function it should check against its primary key in that table and should return the data.

is it possible thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a possibility you can send primary_key name aswell to the function?

Comment: i can send but i dont want that is it possible in the way i am thinking

Answer (score 1):

```
function getdatabyid($table,$pk) {

   $result = pg_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM ". $table);
      if (pg_num_rows($result) > 0) {
         while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
             $result = pg_query("SELECT * FROM ". $table ." WHERE ". $row['Field'] ." = ". $pk ." LIMIT 1"); 

             if(pg_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                return $result;
             }
             else return false;
         }
      }
      else die('Incorrect table name.');
   }    
}
```

Comment: but as the data is increasing the response time will be low

Comment: I've just added `LIMIT 1` to the end of the query, so regardless of the number of rows in table it'll only return the first row as result.

Comment: why would you need a limit if you are filtering on a primary key?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query to get the column names for the primary key:

```
SELECT cu.CONSTRAINT_NAME, cu.COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE cu 
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT tc.* FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS tc 
   WHERE tc.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'YOUR_TABLE_SCHEMA' 
   AND tc.TABLE_NAME = 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME' 
   and TC.CONSTRAINT_TYPE='PRIMARY KEY'
   AND tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME = cu.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
)
```

Then execute another query to get the actual result. This is still pretty inefficient - You better give the primary key name as an argument.

Comment: True; it would be better if you could pass the primary key column name.  But, one comment, I believe it's a bit faster/more efficient if you use the "pg" tables.  Here is a link:  http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Retrieve_primary_key_columns

Comment: @DavidS You have a point. OP is obviously not too worried about effinciency though :)